# Is javascript HtmlEncode at output considered dangerous?

Tags: xss, javascript, encoding

I've read some time ago that htmlEncoding in javascript is a no-go. But that is the case when you first encode the data and then save it in db (for example). In this case, you only rely on javascript to do the encoding and i see why this is dangerous.

But when saving user inputs in database as is and doing htmlEncode at output, does it make sense to only htmlEncode on the server and consider javascript htmlEncoding dangerous?

Comment: Can you link a source or give more details for why you think HTML-encoding with JS is dangerous?

Comment: In general I don't see this opening cross-site scripting risk unless the value is either being used in dangerous javascript (like if it was concatenated into an eval statement) rather than just being displayed in the HTML. Obviously this does nothing to mitigate any server-side injection risks.

Comment: @Arminius: i was referring to client-side htmlEncoding as being dangerous. It's my fault because I haven't been more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

It sometimes makes sense to encode HTML in Javascript, and it is not necessarily dangerous.

For example, if you have an API that returns JSON, it is fine if the that API returns raw strings. Only when you put these strings on the page with Javascript, you have to HTML encode them.

Since this is client-side behavior an attacker can bypass this and remove the encoding. However, this only allows him to attack *his own* browser. XSS is typically dangerous if a script can be run in *someone else's* browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's a well established practice to:

1. Filter input before using / storing - **not** "saving user inputs as is".
2. Encode output before displaying - whether you take it from your own database or from user input.

The encoding you choose depends on the context in which you place the output. For plain HTML context, htmlEncode is right.

Sometimes you run into a use case where you also encode input before storing (comment editors like the one I'm using here now). If you are doing the encoding right, it shouldn't matter which language use (JS or otherwise).

Of course, JavaScript is used both on cliend-side and server-side. If you're relying *only on client-side* to do your #appsec related work (encoding in this case), **that** could be risky - not because it is JS, but because it is client-side.

Comment: I agree with no. 1, but others consider it a matter of preferences. It makes a lot more sense to encode/filter data when storing it, then to encode it each time it's being outputted.

Comment: @Alin If we can be sure that the application filters / encoders we write are the only route to the database, your plan works. Sometimes, there will be other code (or other operations) that could also write to the database. In that case, we might want to assume that the DB queries may not always return encoded data. Hence the *general purpose* advice of encoding before output.